# how to recursively traverse files and directories

Tags: go

When trying to run the program is need to show all .md files, i have a test subfolder with a .md in it, but the scripts dose not find it?

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "strings"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    dir, err := os.ReadDir(".")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    for _, x := range dir {
        if strings.HasSuffix(x.Name(), ".md") {
            fmt.Println(x.Name())
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [filepath.WalkDir](https://pkg.go.dev/path/filepath#WalkDir) to check directories recursively or you can use introduced in 1.16 [filepath.Walk](https://pkg.go.dev/path/filepath#Walk). `os.ReadDir` will work only within provided directory.

```
filepath.Walk(".", func(path string, info fs.FileInfo, err error) error {
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("prevent panic by handling failure accessing a path %q: %v\n", path, err)
        return err
    }

    if strings.HasSuffix(info.Name(), ".md") {
        fmt.Printf("visited file or dir: %q\n", path)
    }

    return nil
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Walkdir](https://pkg.go.dev/path/filepath#WalkDir):

```
package main

import (
   "io/fs"
   "path/filepath"
)


func main() {
   filepath.WalkDir(".", func(s string, d fs.DirEntry, e error) error {
    if e != nil { return e }
    if ! d.IsDir() {
       println(s)
    }
    return nil
 })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add onto the already sufficient responses here is my implementation using the `container/ring` structure

full code [here](https://github.com/ca-std/lib/blob/v0.1.16/dir_graph.go#L46-L97)

```golang
type (
    DirectoryGraph struct {
        RootPath string
        root     *ring.Ring
        Node     *ring.Ring
    }
)

func NewDirectoryGraph(root string) DirectoryGraph {
    r := ring.New(1)
    graph := DirectoryGraph{
        RootPath: root,
        root:     r,
        Node:     r,
    }
    filepath.WalkDir(graph.RootPath, graph.walk)
    return graph
}

func (g DirectoryGraph) walk(s string, d fs.DirEntry, e error) error {
    if e != nil {
        return e
    }
    next := ring.New(1)
    node := g.serialize(s, d, e)
    next.Value = node
    g.root.Link(next).Next()
    return nil
}

// Serializes a file-node
func (g DirectoryGraph) serialize(s string, d fs.DirEntry, e error) FileNode {
    n := FileNode{
        Path: s,
        Dir:  d,
        Sys:  SysInfo{},
    }

    ...

    return n
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate as to why this code is better to use in which conditions ?